# EF4.1 Code First DbContext: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, unity-container, dbcontext

I have a controller action that gets invoked directly, but throws this error:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

I have only found solutions online regarding deferred excecution, but I don't think that applies here, because everywhere I use the context (in this instance) I call either `.ToList()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`. Here is my code:

**CONTROLLER CONTENT**

```
    private IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;
    public MyFavouritesController(
        IAccountServices accountServices,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork
        )
    {
        AccountServices = accountServices;
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int? id = AccountServices.GetCurrentUserId();
        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = this.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath });
        }
        var user = UnitOfWork.UserRepo.Get(id.Value, "Favourites", "Favourites.County", "Favourites.Country");
        //THE ABOVE CALL GETS THE ERROR

        //.....
        return View();
    }
```

**REPOSITORY BASE CLASS**

```
public class RepositoryBase<C, T> : IDisposable
    where C:DbContext, new()
    where T : ModelBase
{
    private DbContext _context;
    public DbContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = new C();
                this.AllowSerialization = true;
            }
            return _context;
        }
        set
        {
            _context = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual T Get(int Id, params string[] includes)
    {
        if (Id > 0)
        {
            var result = Context.Set<T>().Where(t => t.Id == Id);
            foreach (string includePath in includes)
            {
                result = result.Include(includePath);
            }
            return result.FirstOrDefault(); //This is where the error occurs.
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Id is zero (0).");
        }
    }

    //... (More CRUD methods)

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Context != null)
        {
            Context.Dispose(); //Debugger never hits this before the error
        }
    }
}
```

**UNIT OF WORK CLASS**

```
public class UnitOfWork:IUnitOfWork
{
    public UnitOfWork(
        //... DI of all repos
        IUserRepository userRepo
        )
    {
        //... save repos to an local property
        UserRepo = userRepo;

        //create a new instance of the context so that all the repo's have access to the same DbContext
        Context = new Context();

        //assign the new context to all the repo's
        //...
        UserRepo.Context = Context;
    }

    public Context Context { get; set; }

    public IUserRepository UserRepo { get; set; }

    //... (some more repositories)

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose(); //THIS IS NOT HIT AT ALL
    }
}
```

**LASTLY, THE MODEL CONTAINER HAS THIS LINE**

```
_Instance.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
```

As you can see, the index action will recieve a new instance of UnitOfWork which contains a new DbContext object. But at the first call to this context, it throws the above error. This pattern works everywhere else in my code.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The answer below was to use a perRequestLifetimeManager. Here is the implimentation of one in unity:

```
    public class HttpRequestLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
    {
        private string _key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public override object GetValue()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(_key))
                return HttpContext.Current.Items[_key];
            else
                return null;
        }

        public override void RemoveValue()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(_key);
        }

        public override void SetValue(object newValue)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                HttpContext.Current.Items[_key] = newValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you making things so complicated? The `DbContext` already is an implementation of Unit of Work and Repository.

Comment: I'm very new to this and didn't know that. But my reasoning was that I wanted the front-end MVC app to be mostly unaware of the Dbcontext association, making it slightly more loosely coupled. That's why I wrap it all in interfaces.

Comment: What IoC are you using? Have you tried changing the `PerThreadLifetimeManager` to something like a `PerRequestLifetimeManager`?

Comment: Yeah I just did. It works perfectly. Thanks. Put it in an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you're using a `PerThreadLifetimeManager` to control the creation and disposal of your unit of work class. You should probably change it to something like `PerRequestLifetimeManager` if your IoC container supports that.

Comment: Thanks Kristof, that worked perfectly. Unity doesn't support a PerRequestLifetimeManager, but I found a custom implimentation of it on Stackoverflow. I've added it into my question for the benefit of future viewers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your are disposing the Unit Of Work, after wich you are requesting your data, store your data in a Variable after the query then you can release the Unit Of Work instance as well.

Comment: I don't think I am disposing of UnitOfWork. The error occurs INSIDE unitOfWork. I call `.SingleOrDefault()`